# How to know if user is typing or message has been delivered to him in Chat App

Tags: android, laravel, firebase, xmpp, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am building a chatting mobile app. Till now I have studied about FCM and GCM, and I wanna go for FCM but there are no such options where I can get information about whether the user is typing something or Message being delivered to his/her device. Also, there is another protocol named as XMPP. Should I go for XMPP or  FCM is a better approach?

Also, I am using laravel 5.2 in the backend. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: FCM is not design for messaging application, you need to go for XMPP or similar protocol or write your protocol.

Comment: Is there anyway FCM can be used?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to have the status of delivery, whether the message has been received by the endpoint, you need to use XMPP on FCM: [FCM with XMPP official page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/xmpp-server-ref)

You have to set `delivery_receipt_requested` to `true` to check whether the message have been delivered.

To know whether the user is typing a message, you have to implement your own solution on server side, to have full control over this.

Comment: Can you provide any example or sample for the same?